# Prevent div overlap on single page when using multiple min-height 100% divs

Tags: html, css

I have a single page website that is using multiple divs inside a container div.  The height of each of these is set to a min-height of 100%.  This works fine until content inside one of the divs is larger than the browser resolution - the content overlaps the border divs.  I've tried to add position:relative to the container, and position:absolute to the children, but this causes all but the bottom div to disappear.

I've put the following together to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <h1>content</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- About -->
            <div id="about">
                <h1>about</h1>
            <!-- Contact -->
            <div id="contact">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body{height:100%;min-height:100%;min-width:60.000em;font-size:30px;}
#container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:auto;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#content, #about, #contact {
    position: absolute;
}
#content{
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
#about{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#contact {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Here it is in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/s62nr/1/

If I remove the relative/absolute positioning, the size is fine, but the content overlaps:  http://jsfiddle.net/s62nr/2/

What am I missing?

Comment: For those who down-voted this - Down-voting without commenting is useless.  I don't mind getting a down-vote, but help me to 'learn my lesson' so I don't do it again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue (seems this always happen when I ask a question ^^).

The problem was with the fact I was setting the child div height to 100%.  This needs to be removed:

From:

```
#content{
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

To:

```
#content{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I was forcing the content to take up 100% of the browser height.  This stopped the div from expanding automatically like it should.